# How can I post message only if last input was 500ms ago?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have SearchView. When user type something it's posting to log every 500ms but it happens with each symbol. How can I post full string input only when last symbol was inputed 500ms ago?

```
private val delay = 500L //ml
private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

binding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(text: String?): Boolean {
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            val showLogRunnable = Runnable {
                Log.d("SEARCH", "Searching for: $newText")
            }
            handler.postDelayed(showLogRunnable, delay)

            return false
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just dismiss previously set `Runnable` before setting new one

```
    override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        val showLogRunnable = Runnable {
            Log.d("SEARCH", "Searching for: $newText")
        }
        handler.postDelayed(showLogRunnable, delay)
        return false
    }
```

`removeCallbacksAndMessages` will dismiss all previously set `Runnable`s, thus only last one will fire if there will be no input for set `delay`

also don't forget to dismiss all set `Runnable`s when destroying `Activity`/`Fragment` (e.g. in `onDestroy`/`onDestroyView` methods)

Comment: Thank you! How can i destroy them?

Comment: also use `removeCallbacksAndMessages`, don't leave any pending `Runnable`s. non-`null` `val Handler` may stay and will be properly removed from memory by garbage collector when it won't have any pending tasks to fire

Comment: Can you please tell why we should delete it after view destroy? Because of memory leaking?

Comment: exacly :) btw. I strongly recommend [LeakCanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) for detecting leaks in Android apps

Answer (score 1):

Cut all code which you have written in `onQueryTextChange()` method and paste it in `onQueryTextSubmit()`

Cause: `onQueryTextChange()` is called when the text in the `SearcView` is changed and `onQueryTextSubmit()` is called when the text in the `SearchView` is submited by the user.

Here is the correct code which you can copy:

```
private val delay = 500L //ml
private val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

binding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(text: String?): Boolean {
            val showLogRunnable = Runnable {
                Log.d("SEARCH", "Searching for: $newText")
            }
            handler.postDelayed(showLogRunnable, delay)

            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            return false
        }
    })
```

Comment: It will add text only when "search" is pressed :(